# Not able to submit multiple forms on single html page

Tags: php, html, forms

I have problem with forms on one file. 
The problem is that when I click submit ... it submits the first form data instead of the form that the person filled even though as you can see from the code below that I specified a certain id for each form.

I am using a php file to submit the data to mysql

here is my code:

```
case 'upd_chpt':
if($_POST['does'] == 'upd_chpt')
{
    $chId = $_POST['chId'];
    $name = $_POST['name'];
    $nums = $_POST['nums'];
    $mngs = $_POST['mang'];
    $ch_trans = $_POST['ch_trans'];
    $ch_down = $_POST['ch_down'];
    $ch_translate = $_POST['ch_translate'];
    $ch_clean = $_POST['ch_clean'];
    $ch_editor = $_POST['ch_editor'];
    if(!empty($chId) && !empty($name) && !empty($nums) && !empty($mngs) && !empty($ch_trans))
    {
        $mnG = explode(',' , $mngs);
        $qup = $db->query("UPDATE chapter SET ch_name = '".$name."', chapter_num = '".$nums."', manga_id = '".$mnG[0]."', manga_title = '".$mnG[1]."', manga_name = '".$mnG[2]."', ch_down = '".$ch_down."', ch_translate = '".$ch_translate."', ch_clean = '".$ch_clean."', ch_editor = '".$ch_editor."', ch_trans = '".$ch_trans."' WHERE ch_Id = '".$chId."' ");
        if($qup)
        {
            echo "updated successfully";
        }
        else
        {
            echo "erorr ";
        }
    }
    else
    {
        echo "please fill all the fields !";
    }
}
break;
```

html code :

```
<form id="edit_{$ch[ch].ch_Id}">
    <input type="hidden" name="chid" value="{$mn[mn].ch_Id}" />
    <label>chapter number</label>
    <input type="text" id="chaptr" name="chaptr" value="{$ch[ch].chapter_num}" class="short" />
    <label>chapter title </label>
    <input type="text" id="name" name="name" value="{$ch[ch].ch_name}" class="short" />
    <label>manga related to chapter</label>
    <select id="mansga" name="manga">
        {section name='mn' loop=$mng}
            <option value='{$mng[mn].mn_Id},{$mng[mn].mn_title},{$mng[mn].mn_name}' {if $mng[mn].mn_Id==$ch[ch].manga_id}selected="true" {/if}>
                {$mng[mn].mn_name}
            </option>
        {/section}
    </select>
    <label>chapter link</label>
    <input type="text" id="ch_down" name="ch_down" value="{$ch[ch].ch_down}" class="short" />
    <label>all credit goes to</label>
    <input type="text" id="ch_trans" name="ch_trans" value="{$ch[ch].ch_trans}" class="short" />
    <label>translated by</label>
    <input type="text" id="ch_translate" name="ch_translate" value="{$ch[ch].ch_translate}" class="short" />
    <label>cleaned by</label>
    <input type="text" id="ch_clean" name="ch_clean" value="{$ch[ch].ch_clean}" class="short" />
    <label>edited by</label>
    <input type="text" id="ch_editor" name="ch_editor" value="{$ch[ch].ch_editor}" class="short" />
    <label><input type="submit" class="submit" value="تعديل" /></label>
</form>
```

javascript :

```
$('[id^=edit_]').submit(function(){
    var id = $(this).attr('id').split('_')[1];
    var name = $('#name').val();
    var nums = $('#chaptr').val();
    var mang = $('#mansga').val();
    var ch_trans = $('#ch_trans').val();
    var ch_down = $('#ch_down').val();
    var ch_translate = $('#ch_translate').val();
    var ch_clean = $('#ch_clean').val();
    var ch_editor = $('#ch_editor').val();
    $.post("action.php", {does: 'upd_chpt' ,ch_trans:ch_trans, ch_down:ch_down, ch_translate:ch_translate , ch_clean:ch_clean , ch_editor:ch_editor , chId:id , name: name, nums: nums, mang:mang},function(m){
        alert(m);
    });
    return false
});
```

can this code be changed ? and be only php + html without javascript ! ... because I think that id="" is the problem

Comment: Check your html. It's likely your page is not valid. Run it through a html validator first: http://validator.w3.org/

Comment: I am not good with php ... I do not think I can do a demo for my question !

Comment: I see one form. Where are the other form tags?

Comment: the sql database generates them by their id's

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the mistake was on the second line
{$mn[mn].ch_Id} should be {$ch[ch].ch_Id}